# Flask-sqlalchemy 'Models_committed' not calling function registered via decorator

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got a model called Signal (not related to 'signals), which is db.Model using SQLAlchemy.

I'm trying to send, then receive a signal when the Signal models are committed. I'm just trying to get a standard print message out, but I can't seem to get it working. Also tried the decorator method. I can't find much information about how to get Signals working properly on Flask?

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from config import Config
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy, models_committed, before_models_committed


def signal_thing(sender, changes, **kwargs):
    print('hello - is this working?')
    sender.print('hello - is this working')

models_committed.connect(signal_thing, app)
before_models_committed.connect(signal_thing, app)
```

```
@models_commited.connect(app)
def signal_thing(sender, changes, **kwargs):
    print('hello - is this working?')
    sender.print('hello this worked')
```

I'm definitely committing data to my models as they're showing up in my web app, but the print message does nothing. Is there something I'm missing?